# Why my function get 0 results?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Hey what i have here is like 3 functions that works together. But the problem is the last one which is called doesnt iterate over thata becouse it sees is as an empty array. Funny thing is when i do `console.log()` whole object it has a data in that array, but when i log only that array element from that object it is empty. Why ?

Here you is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqoYjd?editors=101

Here is how it looks like:

```
getPlacesInArea: function($scope, types, callback) {
    for (var key in types) {
        if (types.hasOwnProperty(key) && types[key].checked) {
            this.getPlace($scope, key);
        }
    }
    callback($scope);
},
```

So what happens here is just i load data from api to the scope vairable.

```
getAttractionsInArea: function($scope, typesValue) {
    placesService.getPlacesInArea($scope, typesValue, this.showAttractionMarkers);
},
showAttractionMarkers: function($scope) {
    placesService.showPlacesMarkers($scope.map, $scope.attractionsMarkers);
}
```

Here where is the place were the `getPlacesInArea` is called.
In the `getAttractionsInArea` i also pass as a callback `showAttractionMarkers` method.

```
showPlacesMarkers: function(map, markers) {
    if (typeof map != 'undefined') {
        for (var key in markers) {
            if (markers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                mapService.setMapForMarkers(markers[key].items, map);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var type in markers) {
            if (markers.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
                mapService.setMapForMarkers(markers[type].items, null);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Here we are in that function if i do `console.log(markers)` i see that markers[type].items has items. But if i do `console.log(markers[type].items)` the array is empty. Why is that? how can i fix it ?

Here is `console.log(markers);`

```
Object {food: Object, art_gallery: Object, museum: Object, night_club: Object}
```

And here is example of food object

```
food: Object
    checked: true
    icon: null
    items: Array[20]
        0: MarkerWithLabel
        1: MarkerWithLabel
        2: MarkerWithLabel
        3: MarkerWithLabel
        4: MarkerWithLabel
        5: MarkerWithLabel
        6: MarkerWithLabel
        7: MarkerWithLabel
        8: MarkerWithLabel
        9: MarkerWithLabel
        10: MarkerWithLabel
        11: MarkerWithLabel
        12: MarkerWithLabel
        13: MarkerWithLabel
        14: MarkerWithLabel
        15: MarkerWithLabel
        16: MarkerWithLabel
        17: MarkerWithLabel
        18: MarkerWithLabel
        19: MarkerWithLabel
        length: 20
    __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

```js
var $scope,
  objectByString = function(o, s) {
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1');
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');
    var a = s.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
      var k = a[i];
      if (k in o) {
        o = o[k];
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
    return o;
  },
  getMarkersPath = function(amountPath) {
    var paths = amountPath.split('.');

    return paths[paths.length - 1] + 'Markers';
  },
  getAttractionsInArea = function($scope, typesValue) {
    getPlacesInArea($scope, typesValue, 'filters.location.attractions', 'fa-star', showAttractionMarkers);
  },
  showAttractionMarkers = function($scope) {
    var checked = $scope.searchData.filters.location.attractions.checked;

    if (checkPropertyExistence($scope, ['attractionsMarkers'])) {
      showPlacesMarkers($scope.map, $scope.attractionsMarkers, checked);
    }
  },

  clearPlacesMarkers = function($scope, markersPath) {
    if (checkPropertyExistence($scope, [markersPath])) {
      var types = $scope[markersPath];
      for (var type in types) {
        if (types.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
          setMapForMarkers(types[type].items, null);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  showPlacesMarkers = function(map, markers, checked) {
    if (typeof map != 'undefined' && checked) {
      for (var key in markers) {
        if (markers.hasOwnProperty(key) && markers[key].checked) {
          setMapForMarkers(markers[key].items, map);
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (var type in markers) {
        if (markers.hasOwnProperty(type) && markers[type].checked) {
          setMapForMarkers(markers[type].items, null);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  getPlacesInArea = function($scope, types, propertyPath, icon, callback) {
    var markersPath = getMarkersPath(propertyPath);
    this.clearPlacesMarkers($scope, markersPath);

    addToProperty($scope.searchData, propertyPath + '.amount', 0);
    $scope[markersPath] = types;
    types = $scope[markersPath];

    if (typeof $scope.map != 'undefined') {
      for (var key in types) {
        if (types.hasOwnProperty(key) && types[key].checked) {
          this.getPlace($scope, key, propertyPath, icon);
        }
      }
      callback($scope);
    }
  },
  getPlace = function($scope, key, propertyPath, icon) {
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($scope.map),
      request = {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.searchData.location.lat, $scope.searchData.location.lon),
        radius: 700,
        types: [key]
      },
      markersPath = getMarkersPath(propertyPath);

    service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var markers = [],
          amount = objectByString($scope.searchData, propertyPath + '.amount');

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var place = results[i];

          var typeIcon = null;
          if (checkPropertyExistence($scope, [markersPath, key, 'icon'])) {
            typeIcon = objectByString($scope, markersPath + '.' + key + '.icon');
          }

          var markerIcon = (typeIcon !== null ? typeIcon : (icon !== null ? icon : place.icon)),
            marker = addMarker(place.geometry.location, null, markerIcon);

          addInfoBubble(marker, place.name, place.vicinity.substr(0, 70), markerIcon, $scope.map, key.replace(/_/g, ' '));
          markers.push(marker);

          if (checkPropertyExistence($scope, [markersPath, key, 'items'])) {
            $scope[markersPath][key]['items'] = markers;
          }
        }

        addToProperty($scope.searchData, propertyPath + '.amount', amount + markers.length);
      }
    })
  },
  addToProperty = function($searchData, $keyString, $value) {
    var keys = $keyString.split(".");
    lastKeyIndex = keys.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++i) {
      key = keys[i];
      if (!(key in $searchData))
        $searchData[key] = {};
      $searchData = $searchData[key];
    }
    $searchData[keys[lastKeyIndex]] = $value;
  },
  checkPropertyExistence = function(obj, paths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
      if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(paths[i])) {
        return false;
      }
      obj = obj[paths[i]];
    }
    return true;
  },
  addMarker = function(point, map, icon, color) {
    if (typeof color == 'undefined') {
      color = "#000000";
    }
    return new MarkerWithLabel({
      position: point,
      map: map,
      icon: ' ',
      labelContent: '<i class="fa ' + icon + ' fa-2x" style="color:' + color + ';"></i>',
      labelAnchor: point
    });
  },
  addInfoBubble = function(marker, title, content, icon, map, additionalInfo) {
    if (typeof icon == 'undefined') {
      icon = "fa-map-marker";
    }

    if (typeof additionalInfo == 'undefined') {
      additionalInfo = "";
    }

    var bounds = map.getBounds(),
      myOptions = {
        content: "<div class='info'>" +
          "<div class='infoBubble'>" +
          "<h4><i class='fa " + icon + "'></i> " + title + " <small>" + additionalInfo + "</small></h4>" +
          "<p>" + content + "</p>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</div>",
        disableAutoPan: true,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), bounds.getSouthWest().lng()),
        isHidden: false,
        closeBoxURL: ""
      };

    var infobox = new InfoBox(myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      infobox.open(map);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      infobox.close();
    });

    return infobox;

  },
  setMapForMarkers = function(markers, map) {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      try {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
      } catch (e) {

      }
    }
  };

function initialize() {
  $scope = {
    searchData: {
      location: {
        lat: 40.722840,
        lon: -73.999585
      }
    },
    filters: {
      location: {
        attractions: {
          checked: true
        }
      }
    }
  };
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.722840, -73.999585),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  $scope.getAttractionsInArea = function() {
    var value = {
      food: {
        checked: true,
        icon: null,
        items: []
      },
      art_gallery: {
        checked: true,
        icon: null,
        items: []
      },
      museum: {
        checked: true,
        icon: null,
        items: []
      },
      night_club: {
        checked: true,
        icon: null,
        items: []
      }
    };

    getAttractionsInArea($scope, value);
  };
  $scope.showAttractionMarkers = function() {
    showAttractionMarkers($scope);
  };
  $scope.getAttractionsInArea();
}

function show(element) {
  element.checked ? $scope.filters.location.attractions.checked = true : $scope.filters.location.attractions.checked = false;
  $scope.showAttractionMarkers();
}

initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="check" id="xxx" onchange="show(this)" />Show markers
</label>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are trying to do. It would help if you could create a plunkr to demonstrate the issue, or at the very least, post the output of the console.log that has the entire object.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: chrome 44.0.2403.125 m

Comment: @GPicazo markers looks like:
`markers{'food':{items:[]}}` and items array contains google map markers objects. that all

Comment: I added `console.log` to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show markers when callback return (only markers returned)
so when food callback return show only food

```
service.nearbySearch(request, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var markers = [],
        amount = objectByString($scope.searchData, propertyPath + '.amount');

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];

            var typeIcon = null;
            if (localStorageService.checkPropertyExistence($scope, [markersPath, key, 'icon'])) {
                               typeIcon = objectByString($scope, markersPath + '.' + key + '.icon');
                           }

             var markerIcon = (typeIcon !== null ? typeIcon : (icon !== null ? icon : place.icon)),
             marker = mapService.addMarker(place.geometry.location, null, markerIcon);

             mapService.addInfoBubble(marker, place.name, place.vicinity.substr(0, 70), markerIcon, $scope.map, key.replace(/_/g, ' '));
             markers.push(marker);

            if (localStorageService.checkPropertyExistence($scope, [markersPath, key, 'items'])) {
                               $scope[markersPath][key]['items'] = markers;
            }
        }

        localStorageService.addToProperty($scope.searchData, propertyPath + '.amount', amount + markers.length);
        localStorageService.save($scope.searchData, "searchData");

        if (checked)) {
            mapService.setMapForMarkers(markers, $scope.map);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

See comments below

You can try some kind of loader like this. If we assume drinks is the last property of the markers object

```
function dataLoaded () {
  if (markers.drinks.items.length > 1) {
    showPlacesMarkers();
  } else {
    dataLoaded();
  }
}
```

Simple implementation to show you the concept only. Hope this helps

Comment: but type here is a key. so its invalid to do `markers.type.items`
for example `var type = 'food'` `markers.type.items` will not call it

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can call properties of objects using the object.key notation... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: calling `console.log(markers.key.items);` throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`

Comment: also documentation you provided nicely explains why you can't do that.

Comment: it would be markers.keys, which would return an array of keys to all of the properties in the markers object.

I think this is the last time I help people like you though, down-voting me just because you are misinformed and do not understand how objects work...

Comment: And why would i do that ? Looping `for (var key in markers) {}` i also have the key in the `key` vairable. and by getting keys from `markers.keys` i have to do loop also, so whats the point of doing additional code ?

Comment: That was simply to answer your previous comment. when I said 'object.key' notation, it was in the general form. i.e. markers.food = object.key. markers is the object, food is the key.

Apologies for misunderstanding the first part where type is actually a variable. But that simply means type is probably returning the wrong value. Have you tried console.log(type) in the loop just to see what type is returning in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: yes i have, and it has the correct value. the wrong value i get only by for example `markers.food.items` becouse it returns emty array, and when i log all amrkers as `console.log(markers)` it says that `items` arrays in are not empty. the log is show in question in the end.

Comment: The only logical explanation I can think of (and I have come across similar problems before) is that at the time of the console.log the items array was still loading and therefore is empty. The method you used is definitely viable https://jsfiddle.net/2bhdetgv/ as shown on this fiddle. Try putting a timeout on

    console.log(markers.food.items) 

just to see if my theory is correct?

Comment: yes you are correct, and this is the problem im trying to solve. any ideas

Comment: Is there an onload event you can check for? If not, you can write a simple custom one. I'll put it as an edit to my answer above for formatting reasons.

Comment: its a good idea but it throws `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: ah yeah that would happen. Wrap the whole thing in a setInterval of 100ms?

Comment: its bad idea, i dont know how much items there is going to be exacly

Comment: Its not a great solution, I agree. But it will only keep checking until the first item loads and once that is loaded, the rest of the Array should also be loaded.

Best approach would be if there is a ready event for the API that you are using.

Comment: i added a snipped if you want to see it. i just copied the code from my files and fixed console errors.